# jQuery-UI drop doesn't really drop anything in the droppable

Tags: jquery-ui

I notice in the jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/T4sGh/1/ - that when you drag and drop the red box onto the beige box, it *looks* like the red box goes inside the beige box, but in the HTML it actually becomes a sibling of the beige box and is just given offsets to place it *over* the beige box:

```
<body style="cursor: auto;">
   <div id="box" class="ui-droppable"></div>
   <div id="redBox" class="ui-draggable" style="position: relative; left: 89px; top: -213px;"></div>
</body>
```

This was unexpected.  I don't recall any jQuery-UI documentation that talks about this.Does anyone have a feel what what is going on here and perhaps be able to point me to some documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `draggable` and `droppable` do not change the DOM by default. If you want to do that you can utilize the events that they expose. Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4sGh/5/) updated. I am using the drop event in order to reposition the `draggable` inside your `droppable` container on drop:

```
var cell_dropOps = {     
    drop : box_drop,        
    accept : '#redBox',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        ui.draggable.css({ top: 0, left: 0});
    }
};
```

Comment: "The draggable and droppable do not change the DOM by default."  Yes.  That's the key. It _looks_ like the droppable gets dropped inside the droppee, and so I assumed it was in there and spent a fair amount of time trying to figure out why `$(this).find(ui.droppable)` always came up empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the example on this [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) page, you'll notice that this is the default behavior.

If you wish to make `dragable` object a child of `dropable` object, you will have to append it manually in your drop function like:

```
 $(this).append($(ui.helper[0]));
```

The whole purpose of mentioning `accept : '#redBox'` is that when you drop `#redBox` on your `dropable` div, the drop event gets fired.